# How do I send data to an android app from Google App Engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

As I understand it, there are two ways to send data from GAE to my app:

1. The app does a request and the server sends the data as a response.
2. The server sends the data directly to the app *without the app doing a request*.

I know how to send data with (1) but how do I send data with (2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for Google Cloud messaging which helps "Push"ing the messages from your server to your app (via GCM Service)

Read for details

> http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html